# PowwrShell/SPO: Download directly into a library

Tags: powershell, azure-blob-storage, sharepoint-online

I wanted to ask, if it is possible with PowerShell to download a file from a webpage directly into a SharePoint Online library?

Alternatively, a download into a Azure Blob Storage would also work.

Thank you in advance.

I already tried the following without success:

`Invoke-WebRequest -URI $URL -OutFile https://sharepoint.site.com/sites/library/file.docx`

```
$URL = "htpps://webpage.com/file.docx"
$Path = "https://sharepoint.site.com/sites/library/file.docx"

(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile ($URL, $Path)
```

Comment: HTTPS is a protocol.  You just want to write without protocol : Invoke-WebRequest -URI $URL -OutFile \\SERVER_NAME\library\file.docx.  The folder has to be shared and allow users access.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure to try it with appropriate permissions.